# EXC_BAD_ACCESS when setting Integer to anything else than zero

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, core-data, exc-bad-access

I have this object:

```
@interface Song : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *songName;
@property (nonatomic) int32_t achievedPoints;
```

When I set the properties like this

```
Song *song1 = [[SongStore sharedStore] createSong]; 
song1.songName = @"Song 1";
song1.achievedPoints = 0;
```

everything works, however once I try to set the `achievedPoints` variable to something else than 0 I get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS.

This is what the `createSong` method does:

```
- (Song *)createSong {
    double order;
    if ([allSongs count] == 0) {
        order = 1.0;
    } else {
        order = [[allSongs lastObject] orderingValue] + 1.0;
    }

    Song *p = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Song" inManagedObjectContext:context];

    [p setOrderingValue:order];
    [allSongs addObject:p];
    return p;
}
```

I have no idea why getting the value and setting it to 0 works but anything else than zero crashes the program. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Your code does not demonstrate the issue; `achievePoints` isn't even referenced anywhere in the receiving class.

Comment: not int32_t only use int

Comment: @GauravPatel That statement is not true; there is nothing wrong with using `int32_t`.

Comment: @trojanfoe `song1.achievedPoints = 0;`

Comment: The question is: How is the achievedPoints attribute defined in your object model? Is it an int32?

Comment: @MilKyWaY That code is not in the receiving class, but rather somewhere outside of it.

Comment: @trojanfoe What do you mean? song1.achievedPoints = 0; is the line that causes trouble when it is not zero.

Comment: @trojanfoe so what? `@interface Song : NSManagedObject` also lies within

Comment: @TheEye It is defined as Integer 32 type.

Comment: @GauravPatel please dont poste false information if you are not sure. NSInteger will always be at least 32 bits long. If it is 64 bits, your number will be sign extended to match . It will not cause run-time errors.

Comment: @Alex What I mean is, I cannot see any use of the `achievedPoints` in the `Song` class.  You show setting it outside the `Song` class, but don't show how it's actually being used within the `Song` class.

Comment: @MilKyWaY I don't know what you are talking about.  The code `song1.achievedPoints = 0;` is not within the `Song` class, and that's what I'm interested in.

Comment: Try recreating the class from your object model.  It probably was not generated to use scalars, and so it is trying to use the pointer value instead.

Comment: @trojanfoe please don't misunderstand my point. I said achievedPoints lies with in the songs class and nothing is wrong there for setting `song1.achievedPoints = 0`

Comment: @trojanfoe In `Song.m` I have `@dynamic achievedPoints;`. It isn't used from within the `Song` class, but how does that change the nature of the problem that setting to something else than 0 crashes?

Comment: Did you write Song.h/Song.m yourself, or did you use "Create NSManaged Object subclass ..." in Xcode?

Comment: @Alex It's crucial to finding the issue. If it's `@dynamic` (important information) and you are using Core Data then it will be turned into calls to `setValueForKey:` which is likely the issue.

Comment: @MartinR I did indeed write it myself. I will create it again using "Create NSManaged Object subclass" now, I think this is also what borrrden referred to.

Comment: @Alex: Yes, you probably made some error in the accessor methods in Song.m. Using the generated classes is much less error-prone. You can specify "Use scalar types ..." in the "Create NSManaged Object subclass" dialog if you want `uint32_t` instead of `NSNumber`.

Comment: @Alex Yes, that is what I meant as well

Comment: @MartinR Using the generated classes with scalar types solved the issue. Thanks a lot! Also thanks to everybody else.

Comment: @borrrden: You were the first to figure out the real problem. Will you write an answer so that Alex can accept it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has happened to me once before.  I don't know exactly which settings gets messed up, but there is a setting in your managed object model, I think, that controls whether or not the class should use primitive values (int, float, etc) or object values (NSNumber *, etc) to set its values.  If this gets messed up, and you think you are setting a primitive when you are actually setting an object the following will happen:

```
//song1.achievedPoints = 0;
song1.achievedPoints = (NSNumber *)0x00000000; 
//This is OK because it is the same as nil

//song1.achievedPoints = 1;
song1.achievedPoints = (NSNumber *)0x00000001; //You can see why this is bad!
```

My solution was to regenerate the class via the **Create NSManagedObject Subclass** template, making sure that *Use Scalar Values for Primitives* was checked.

Answer (score 0):

This issue happened to me because the entity wasn't correctly linked to my class files. When this happened, Core Data creates its own subclass dynamically, rather than using my own, and that subclass's setters expect boxed primitives.

You can fix this by ensuring the "Class" property of your entity in the model file is set to the correct class, and not the default `NSManagedObject`.

[image: Entity Configuration]

When you use XCode's **Create NSManagedObject Subclass** template, XCode will automatically set this value for the corresponding entity in the model file. This is probably what fixed borrrden's problem. However, you should be able to achieve the same result without creating new files by ensuring this value is set correctly.