# Core Data EXC_BAD_ACCESS for non-zero integer values

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, core-data

I have two core data models with int64_t properties. One of them works fine while the other throws EXC_BAD_ACCESS when I try to assign a non-zero value to the integer field. I've read the answers that say to recreate the NSManagedObject child class and I have done with no success. The broken class looks like this:

```
@interface NoteObject : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic) int64_t remoteID;
@property (nonatomic) int64_t remoteArticleID;

@property (strong, nonatomic) ArticleObject *article;

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *status;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *token;

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *title;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *noteContent;

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSDate *pubDate;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSDate *modDate;

@end

@implementation NoteObject

@dynamic remoteID;
@dynamic remoteArticleID;

@dynamic article;

@dynamic status;
@dynamic token;

@dynamic title;
@dynamic noteContent;

@dynamic pubDate;
@dynamic modDate;

@end
```

The offending line is in this block:

```
_noteObject = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Note" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

_noteObject.remoteArticleID = 0; // this works
_noteObject.remoteArticleID = 1; // this crashes
```

What really has me stumped is that in another model I have the same fields with the same types and they will accept non-zero values without any trouble:

```
bookmarkObject = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Bookmark" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

bookmarkObject.remoteArticleID = 0; // this works
bookmarkObject.remoteArticleID = 1; // this works, too
```

Is there anything in my .xcdatamodeld file that could be causing this?

**EDIT**

My data models look like this:

[image: NoteObject Data Model]
[image: BookmarkObject Data Model]

Comment: Are there any differences in the configuration of the remoteArticleID field for your NoteObject vs. your Bookmark in the .xcdatamodeld file?

Comment: Did you write the managed object subclass files yourself or are they generated by Xcode?

Comment: You should think about using `mogenerator` to create your managed object classes

Comment: Okay, I've added images of the data model editor. As I said earlier, the classes were generated by Xcode.

Comment: @Raider: I just wonder because the Xcode generated class files usually have `@property (nonatomic, retain)`, not `@property (strong, nonatomic)`.

Comment: @MartinR That's correct, I refactored them after generating the class. According to Cocoa, they should be syntactically equivalent. In either case, it's the int64_t properties that are throwing the exception.

Comment: @Raider: You are right, it is equivalent. But there must be some difference between the two entities, and the crash would for example happen if the property is not declared as a scalar, but as NSNumber in the .h file.

Comment: @Raider: The entity is called "Note" in your Xcode screenshot, but you have shown the interface for class "NoteObject".

Comment: @MartinR "Note" is the entity name, while "NoteObject" is the class name: `_noteObject = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Note" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, in case anyone else is having this issue, I never found a satisfactory answer for why one entity was working and the other wasn't. My workaround was to refactor the properties to use `NSNumber` wrappers instead of primitive `int64_t` values.

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSNumber *remoteID;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSNumber *remoteArticleID;
```

Of course, that means boxing/unboxing the integer values.

```
_noteObject.remoteArticleID = [NSNumber numberWithInt:1];

int intVar = [_noteObject.remoteArticleID intValue];
```

Comment: Strange but this thing works for me. There must be some way to direct deal with primitive data type.

Answer (score 5):

I had exactly the same problem.

It appears that xcode (or perhaps the compiler, or perhaps the two between them) sometimes gets confused when you manually edit properties in the NSManagedObject - it ends up treating our integers as pointers and trying to access memory directly - hence the EXC_BAD_ACCESS.

Anyway, as this question explains: [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15001656/exc-bad-access-when-setting-integer-to-anything-else-than-zero), the solution is to delete your old class (obviously copy out any custom code so you can paste it back again later) and then get xcode to regenerate it for you (select the entity in the data model and select "Editor / Create NSManagedObject subclass..."). In the dialogue that appears, make sure "Use scalar properties for primitive data types" is ticked.

You may have to manually edit the resulting class to turn some non scalar properties back into objects (I had a date object which it turned into something other than NSDate - I forget exactly what, but it accepted the manually made edit back to NSDate).

It worked for me. Hope it works for you.

Ali

Comment: +1 Added some more context to an existing answer. ( you could have marked the question also as duplicate)

Answer (score 0):

In your model file, check that the entity's "Class" property is set to the appropriate class, and not the default `NSManagedObject`.

[image: Entity settings]

If you leave it as `NSManagedObject`, Core Data will create properties itself on a custom `NSManagedObject` subclass it generates itself, rather than using your own subclass. Most getters and setters will appear to work, but you may have issues with non-boxed primitive properties and custom getters and setters.